# best way to stack function calls in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chaining

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.props.syncFirebaseToStore(user);
        thenCallThis()
        thenCallThis2()
      }
  }
```

whats the best way to do the above? basically I want to call 3 functions but only after the previous one has finished executing?

I tried using resolve new Promise but don't think I quite have the syntax right. I would like to chain it with `.then()` ideally

Comment: Are you using any middle-ware library

Comment: you could use async/await

Answer (score 0):

If your functions are already returning `Promise` instances - it's pretty easy to chain them up and attach an error handler, something like this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        //Make sure that this call and the rest return Promises
        this.props.syncFirebaseToStore(user)
         .then(callThis1)
         .then(callThis2)
         .catch((err) => {console.error(err)})

      }
  }
```

Say you want to pass arguments down the chain so that previous call returns something used by the next one, then you would do something like this:

```
  this.props.syncFirebaseToStore(user) //returns result1 when Promise resolved
             .then((results1) => {return callThis1(results1)}) //consumes results1, returns results2
             .then((results2) => {return callThis2(results2)})
             .catch((err) => {console.error(err)})
```

Answer (score 0):

With promises:

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
    return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (!user) return Promise.reject('No user!')

        return this.props.syncFirebaseToStore(user)
          .then(thenCallThis)
          .then(thenCallThis2)
    })
}
```

Notes:
I've assumed that this.props.syncFirebaseToStore() returns a promise.
Wrapping the arrow function body in curlies kills the implicit return.

Answer (score -1):

with async await the above code could be written as such

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) => {
      if (user) {
        await this.props.syncFirebaseToStore(user);
        await thenCallThis()
        await thenCallThis2()
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: blow up meaning ?

Comment: aah, my bad, the async keyword should be inside the inner function. I will modify the code